# Fetching Facebook API objects from their public URL

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm helping out building an indexer for Facebook posts/photos/notes/etc.

The idea is that given a public Facebook URL, I can fetch their information using Facebook API. This has mostly worked for a lot of URL patterns, but some seem really hard to figure out if it's even possible. They are:

- Albums with set param: https://www.facebook.com/alexsander.lepletier/media_set?set=a.10151933894649198.1073741851.531549197
- A photo in an album: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151256245188625&set=a.10151256241688625.559837.838813624
- A photo in an album with a slightly different URL pattern: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151256245188625&set=t.100002233344951

It looks like I have some `a.xxx` and `t.xxx` album ID that is not directly usable in the Graph API Explorer.

How to, based I have these URLs at hand, can I use these IDs with the Facebook Graph API, or how to  convert these to something Facebook Graph API recognizes?

Comment: I don't want to scrape the page, I want to use the Facebook Graph API provide I have an URL. It's not scraping.

Comment: I've tried the `fbid=` part and all the portions as an ID, it's not it.

Comment: did you try with a user token?

Comment: I've tried through the Graph API Explorer, which provides a token for me. It's not a permission issue: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=10151256245188625&version=v2.2

Comment: did you try with a user token of the user who uploaded/owns the picture, and did you include the user_photos permission?

Comment: The photos are public. They are not restricted. I don't/can't have the user token, but as I said before, it's not a permission issue. I can't, with my own access token, access my own photo with the fbid portion with URL on the Graph API. I insist, this is not a permission issue.

Comment: it does not matter if they are public, they are on a user profile. in any case it is worth trying with user_photos ;)

Comment: check out my answer, it is definitely as i suspected. i just tested it with public photos of myself and other profiles in the api explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this with the Graph API Explorer. You can only get the photos with a User Access Token of the user who uploaded the picture, and you need to authorize the user with the `user_photos` permission. Using the ID after "fbid=" works that way, and that way only.

"Public" does not always mean you can get it with the Graph API. It makes sense if you think about privacy, an App should not be able to grab public stuff from a user profile if the user did not authorize the App.

Comment: I have tried with the user_photos permission and indeed the fbid works for my photos, sorry for the rant. The weird part is that the API docs state otherwise: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/photo "Any valid access token for any photo with public privacy settings."

Comment: yeah, it is a bit weird, the next line seems to be correct: "For any photos uploaded by someone, and any photos in which they have been tagged - A user access token for that person with user_photos permission"

Comment: I've reported a bug at the Facebook bug tracker: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1569724479914127